# data structure tree complexity

Tags: tree

I have this [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9FqH.png)

[image: tree]

I am sure that it is a max heap, and I don't know about if it is a full tree because in course notes it says a binary tree is a full tree when every non-leave node have two children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Max-heap](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ddb92cea328a64098e3219bd021ff6cb?convert_to_webp=true). there you have an example, and yes, your tree is a max-heap.

Also, for it to be a full tree, each level HAS to be filled with nodes, like in [this](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html) example. Your tree is a complete tree, but not a full tree. Hope this helps.

To be a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), it has to respect some rules.
For example, you have the root, left and right child.

```
   2
1    3
```

The left tree (made by 1 single node here) has to have lower values than the root, and the right tree (here made by 1 single node) has to have all the values greater than the root. So no, your tree is not a binary search tree.

Regarding the second question (you should post 1 question / post)... The worst case is O(n) if the tree is not a binary search tree. If it is a **binary search tree**, you get O(log n) in worst case, IF you have a balanced tree!.

If you have a binary tree, worst case is O(n) because of this valid [binary search tree](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/niemann/s_fig33.gif).

A [balanced binary search tree](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/10.-Balanced-or-not.png) is optimized for different kind of operations. In a general tree, depending how it is built, worst cases will be O(n)!

Answer (score 0):

"A binary heap is a heap data structure created using a binary tree." -  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

A binary-tree means each node has 2 child references.

If each node in a binary-tree does not have two children it is not a full-tree.

`O(logn)` for searching because at each node, you split the dataset in half (because there are at most 2 children), going left or right to search until you reach a leaf or the data you are searching for.